# Installing SIP 4.16.4 and PyQt5.3.1 for Python 3.4 x64 on Windows 8.1

Tags: python, qt, makefile, python-sip

Downloaded SIP 4.16.4.zip(*windows source*) from [riverbankcomputing](http://riverbankcomputing.com) - Unpacked and ran `configure.py` from within the folder. Sub-Directories sipgen, sip-lib are now in the `Python34` directory along with `sipconfig.py` and Makefile.

I am unable to run any of the Makefiles either in the sipgen/sip-lib sub folders or in the main `Python34` folder. Ran the installer for Py3.4-Qt5.3.1-x64 and the following *test code* from within PyCharm3.4.1

The code runs with exit code 0, but within the PyCharm editor, the import statements are flagged as

> Cannot find reference 'QtCore' in '__init__.py'

and

> Cannot find reference 'QtWidgets' in '__init__.py'

The `Qt***.pyd` (QWidget, QLabel, etc) files from:
*Python34\lib\site-packages\PyQt5*
used in the code are flagged by `PyCharm` as **Unresolved reference**.

My goal is to install *PyQt5.3.1x64 for Python 3.4x64 on Windows 8.1* - I have searched extensively and most of the doc/posts I've encountered are for Visual Studio applications or leads off into some tangent that is not applicable.

I'm looking for a concise procedure to install on windows and am not sure if I should also install some base QT by running qt-opensource-windows-x86-1.6.0-6-online.exe installer.
I believe the problem is with not being able to run the make and make install steps for the Windows environment. There is a **Makefile** in each of the following directories...
Python34: *python34\sipgen and python34\siplib*

Do I need to run a make and install using each of these and if so how is this done on Windows 8.1?

### TEST CODE

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Form(QWidget):
    def \__init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).\__init__(parent)

        nameLabel = QLabel("Name:")
        self.nameLine = QLineEdit()
        self.submitButton = QPushButton("&Submit")
        buttonLayout1 = QVBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout1.addWidget(nameLabel)
        buttonLayout1.addWidget(self.nameLine)
        buttonLayout1.addWidget(self.submitButton)

        self.submitButton.clicked.connect(self.submitContact)

        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        # mainLayout.addWidget(nameLabel, 0, 0)
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout1, 0, 1)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello Qt")

        def submitContact(self):
        name = self.nameLine.text()

if name == "":
    QMessageBox.information(self, "Empty Field",
                                "Please enter a name and address.")
    return
else:
    QMessageBox.information(self, "Success!",
                                "Hello %s!" % name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = Form()
    screen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

In another post it was suggested that the **unresolved references** are caused by a bug in PyCharm. The code runs fine but the IDE sets flags throughout for all the Qt components. If anyone else is trying to install sip and Qt5 on windows 8 and needs help contact me and I will be glad to give step by step instructions using Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt.